# Read excel with a particular word in title

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a folder which may or may not have multiple excel file.

The name of the excel files can change with time, but there would be one specific keyword that will always be in the name of the excel.
For test purposes, let the **keyword** be `Fruits`

For the excel which have fixed name like `Fruits_Pineapple.xlsx` the code works:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_excel(r'c:\mypath\Fruits_Pineapple.xlsx')
```

But I can have excel file like `Fruits_Pineapple`, `Fruits_Apple`,`Vegetables` etc. I want to know how can I read the excel with `contains` functionality.

I have searched SO but surprisingly couldn't find any solution!!

Comment: Why not just check and select the filenames before passing them to pd.read_excel ?

Comment: So you are suggesting, I run a loop on the folder through `os.walk` , check the file names, whichever fits the criteria, store the name and then call `read_excel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have no idea of how many (if any) excel files are valid in your folder, you can do the following using `glob`-

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

excel_list = glob.glob("*Fruits*.xlsx") 
#or whatever extension you have, you can give a relative path or complete path.
for excel in excel_list:
    pd.read_excel(excel)
    #Whatever else you need to do below
```